# Direct Line API - Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

"You can enable communication between your bot and your own client application by using the Direct Line API."
The way I see, Bot (created using botframework) itself is an endpoint. Why can't we use Bot's API directly to communicate with the bot? 
Why do we need Direct Line?

Comment: Context: [Is there any way to connect directly to a chatbot without using the direct line api?](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1006)

Answer (score 8):

The Bot Framework provides tools and services to help you build, deploy, and publish bots, including the [BotBuilder SDK for .NET and Node.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder), the [Bot Developer Portal](https://botframework.com), and the Bot Connector.

[The Direct Line protocol](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS) is provided so you can connect your bot to a custom chat interface, aka WebChat, or to a custom web or mobile app.

You don't need to use the Direct Line API if you only want to communicate with your bot via the supported channels such as Skype, Bing, Slack, MS Teams, Telegram, Twilio SMS, and more.

While the bot is a type of API application, it does not exist in isolation, and requires the Bot Framework channel connector service in order to relay your bot's messages to the various connected channels such as Skype or Slack.  If you sent messages directly to your Bot's API without having it connected to the rest of the ecosystem, the bot wouldn't know where to direct the respective messages.

Bot Framework Architectural Overview
[image: Bot Framework Overview]

For more information on Bot Framework architecture, see: [How the Bot Framework works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/overview-how-bot-framework-works).